# Error while executing hql query on Jboss-eap-7.1.0 server with java 1.8.0_121 + SQL Server 2017

Tags: java-8, sql-server-2017, jboss-eap-7

Greetings for the day,

I am executing following query on jboss-eap-7.1.0 with jdk 1.8.0_121 using SQL server 2017.

```
select from  UserDO user where user.userStatusCd <> 'ACTIVE'
```

My observation is, when we are using <> operator then there is an error. If we use "**not in ('ACTIVE')**" then it run successfully. Its okay about <>, but what to use for >= (Greater than or equal to) or some special characters like "**|**" (pipe). I can use the **beetween** keyword, but then how to handle for special characters? I am getting following error, can you please suggest why it is occurring or what's the solution or for time being whats the workaround for this.

```
[ERROR] java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <<> at index 0: <>.class
[ERROR]         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]         at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] find by example failed
org.hibernate.QueryException: Incorrect query syntax [select from  com.c2lbiz.symbiosys.systemcommon.dataobjects.security.UserDO user where user.userStatusCd <> 'ACTIVE']
        at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:232)
        at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
```

One thing I didn't understand, why it is giving **java.nio.file.InvalidPathException**? ***This query successfully gets executed on wildfly server but on eap-7 server, it is giving error.***

Following is my java code to execute hql:

```
    {
            query = session.createQuery(baseIO.getQuery());
            List<Object[]> results =  query.list();
            baseIO.setList(results);
    }
```

Along with that, in my log there is no date and time . Can you suggest for that also?

Many thanks in advance, feel free to ask if you need any.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Jboss 7.1.1 with setting following option as TRUE, ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL

./bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true

Jboss 7.1.0 does not provide this solution so you might not want to waste time there, Ideally Jboss changed this from 6.4.18+([RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)) patch but somehow missed out in 7.1.0.

for more visit Jboss backlog, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-13710